# How we can get all MarkLogic databases document counts in single XQuery Code?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

We need to generate a report using XQuery where we need details like database sizes and database document counts(Total documents value).

We had the below XQuery code from which we can get the database names and database size, but we also want to include database document counts which are coming in AdminUI.

```
for $db-id in xdmp:databases()
let $db-name := xdmp:database-name($db-id)
let $db-size :=
  fn:sum(
    for $f-id in xdmp:database-forests($db-id)
    let $f-status := xdmp:forest-status($f-id)
    let $space := $f-status/forest:device-space
    let $f-name := $f-status/forest:forest-name
    let $f-size :=
      fn:sum(
        for $stand in $f-status/forest:stands/forest:stand
        let $stand-size := $stand/forest:disk-size/fn:data(.)
        return $space
      )
    return $f-size
  )
order by $db-size descending
return $db-name || " = " || $db-size
```

something like

```
return $db-name || " = " || $db-size || "=" || $db-count
```

Using below, we can get document count in a single database(whatever is selected in QC dropdown) but I need to run the below command for all databases in a single script.

```
xdmp:estimate(doc())
```

Any help or suggestions on this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the `document-count` with [`xdmp:forest-counts()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-counts) and add them up, like you have done for size:

```
declare namespace forest = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest";
for $db-id in xdmp:databases()
let $db-name := xdmp:database-name($db-id)
let $db-size :=
  fn:sum(
    for $f-id in xdmp:database-forests($db-id)
    let $f-status := xdmp:forest-status($f-id)
    let $space := $f-status/forest:device-space
    let $f-name := $f-status/forest:forest-name
    let $f-size :=
      fn:sum(
        for $stand in $f-status/forest:stands/forest:stand
        let $stand-size := $stand/forest:disk-size/fn:data(.)
        return $space
      )
    return $f-size
  )
let $db-count := 
  fn:sum(
    for $forest-id in xdmp:database-forests($db-id)
    let $forest-counts := xdmp:forest-counts($forest-id)
    return $forest-counts/forest:document-count/fn:data(.)
  )
order by $db-size descending
return $db-name || " = " || $db-size || ", " || $db-count
```

If you did want to use `xdmp:estimate(doc())` then you could use [`xdmp:invoke-function()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:invoke-function) and specify the content `database` to execute against in the options:

```
declare namespace forest = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest";
for $db-id in xdmp:databases()
let $db-name := xdmp:database-name($db-id)
let $db-size :=
  fn:sum(
    for $f-id in xdmp:database-forests($db-id)
    let $f-status := xdmp:forest-status($f-id)
    let $space := $f-status/forest:device-space
    let $f-name := $f-status/forest:forest-name
    let $f-size :=
      fn:sum(
        for $stand in $f-status/forest:stands/forest:stand
        let $stand-size := $stand/forest:disk-size/fn:data(.)
        return $space
      )
    return $f-size
  )
let $db-count := 
  xdmp:invoke-function(
    function(){ xdmp:estimate(doc())}, 
    <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
      <database>{$db-id}</database>
    </options>)
order by $db-size descending
return $db-name || " = " || $db-size || ", " || $db-count
```